# is there the difference between method invocation and message passing in OOP?

Tags: c#, oop

I reading a book about OOP titled An introduction to Object oriented programming. The book is written by Timothy BUDD.

[In the book he said](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Ebudd/Books/oopintro2e/info/chap01.pdf#page=8), I quote:

> Action is initiated in object-oriented programming by the
> transmission of a message to an agent (an object) responsible for
> the action. The message encodes the request for an action and is
> accompanied by any additional information (arguments) needed to
> carry out the request. The receiver is the object to whom the
> message is sent. If the receiver accepts the message, it accepts the
> responsibility to carry out the indicated action. In response to a
> message, the receiver will perform some method to satisfy the
> request.

Please note the use of term *message* and *method*.

I was introduced to OOP in C# and I know what methods are. What confuses me is the term message. Are messages and methods or method invocation like :
`object.Method()`

the same thing or do they refer to different concepts. What are messages anyways ?

Understand if there is a difference between method invocations and message passing.